# How to copy specific rows from csv file to another csv file based on specific column?

Tags: python, csv

Let's suppose that this is my data.

```
 frame.number    frame.len   frame.cap_len   Packets_Type  
  1               100           100           ICMP_tt   
  2                64            64           UDP   
  3               100           100           ICMP_tt   
  4                87            64           ICMP_nn
  5               100           100           ICMP_tt   
  6                87            64           ICMP_nn
  7               100           100           ICMP_tt   
  8                87            64           ICMP_nn
  9                87            64           ICMP_nn
```

I put my data in a csv file, I want to extract rows where `Packets_Type` is equal to `ICMP_tt`

```
import csv
f = open("file.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
writer = open("newfile.csv",'wb')
writer = csv.writer(writer, delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    if row['Packets_Type'] == 'ICMP_tt':
        writer.writerow(row)
```

By executing those lines of code, I found this error:

```
    writer.writerow(row)
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: You're mixing two approaches. You use `DictReader` to read in data as a dict, then try to write it back out as a list.

Comment: You used `csv.DictReader ` to import but then `csv. writer` to export. Use `csv.DictWriter` to export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are importing your data using `csv.DictReader`, while at the same time you are exporting the data with `csv.writer`. `csv.writer` expects an iterable (`list` or `tuple`), but the row values are dictionaries. So, the best way to save your data would be to stay consistent and use `csv.DictWriter`. The following should work:

```
import csv


with open("file.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    with open("newfile.csv", "wb") as f_out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames, delimiter=",")
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            if row['Packets_Type'] == 'ICMP_tt':
                writer.writerow(row)
```

I hope this proves useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using `pandas` this could be easily done by:

```
import pandas as pd

reader = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
writer = reader[reader['Packets_Type']=='ICMP_tt']
writer.to_csv('newfile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: It gives me this error:  sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (2,5,21,25,26,28,30,31,32,61,63,64,66,67,87,151,158) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

reader = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=',')
writer = reader[reader['Packets_Type']=='ICMP_tt']
writer.to_csv('newfile.csv', index=False)import pandas as pd
```

adding sep=',' should solve the error